# Compile and merge coffeescript and javascript using grunt

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I have included a library written in Javascript, and also have some coffeescript code which depends on these libraries.

When I publish using GRUNT I want to create a single Javascript file which is made by combining all the JS and Coffee files together. Apparently neither [grunt-contrib-uglifyjs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) nor [Grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) supports such kind of behavior. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` to do that.

For example, in your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // EDIT: TO COMPILE YOUR COFFEESCRIPT
    coffee: {
      "default": {
        src: paths.coffee_src,
        dest: paths.js_dir,
        options: {
          preserve_dirs: true,
          base_path: paths.coffee_dir
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['assets/javascripts/libs/underscore/underscore.js', 'assets/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery.js', 'assets/javascripts/libs/json2/json2.js', 'assets/javascripts/libs/handlebars-wycats/dist/handlebars.js', 'assets/javascripts/libs/backbone/backbone.js', 'assets/javascripts/libs/marionette/lib/backbone.marionette.js', 'assets/javascripts/*.js', 'assets/javascripts/utilities/*.js', 'assets/javascripts/models/*.js', 'assets/javascripts/collections/*.js', 'assets/javascripts/modules/**/**/*.js'],
        dest: '<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
    // ...
    // EDIT: TO MINIFY YOUR CONCATENATED JS
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    // ...
```

Here I'm concatenating all files in that order (starting with underscore.js), so, you'll have a single js file with all those files, in the specific order that you desire.

Check [this documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) for more information.

Comment: this would not minify nor obfuscate the output file. Moreover it will not work with coffeescripts.

Comment: Please, check my updated answer. You will have to use `coffee` to compile coffeescript in js first, then use `concat` to concatenate you js and compiled coffeescript files, and then use `uglify` to minify it.

Comment: are you Compiling coffee files to a temp location and then merging them with the already present js files?

Comment: You can choose wherever you want, don't need to be necessarily a temporary folder. You can create a compiled files directory and then ignore it using `.gitignore`

Comment: That's what I am doing right now. It would have been so much better if there was a plugin that could do the same thing in one go.

Comment: You don't need a plugin to do that. Your Gruntfile is just one file, and it was made to perform this tasks for you. You can use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean `grunt-contrib-clean` to clear your temporary folders after you generate your assets.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt is a nodejs file and execute like nodejs. So try this:

```
require('child_process').exec('coffee --compile --output lib/ src/',  function () {
    /*add callback or use execSync */
});
```

Just edit coffee command.

Comment: how do I merge them with javascript files?

Comment: And concat compiled js file by [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat), for example.